# Magento, redifine pricing method, reload price according to quantity

Tags: ajax, magento, reload

I'm trying to build a new pricing method and I want to reload the price according to the quantity and the options in the product view (before adding to cart).

With an Ajax controller, I managed to solve the second problem : when you modify the quantity, I can change the price box content

But my problem here is : there are so many different Model functions in code/core/Mage/Catalog/Product/Type/Price.php so I can't figure what function I need to modify. Maybe it's on an other spot like in js/varien/product.js.

I have to admit : I'm kinda lost.

Thank you very much for you help !

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, the 'cart' and adding to the 'cart' is part of the quote system.  Each quote has several quote items that are basically quantity, configuration and price for each of the 'items' in the cart.

If you are already updating the price consistently on the product page, you should be able to use an observer model to observe the `<sales_quote_save_after>` event and modify the price of certain items based on quantity desired.  This will trigger every time they change qty in the cart or when the actual item is added to the cart for the first time.